# Не могу вытащить body c request запроса

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Как я могу забрать body (хотя бы присвоить на глобальную переменную ) в этом коде? У меня пишет ошибку.

Сам код:

```
var request = require('request');
var temp1='';
var username = 'admin'
var password = '123456'
var options = {
    url: 'http://EXample/Company3/hs/index/json',
    auth: {    user: username,  password: password    }
}

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }

    temp1 = body;
 });

 console.log(temp1);
```

Comment: в данном коде опечатка: не хватает `;` перед `console.log("temp1")`, в остальном вопрос дубликат вопросов про получение значения из асинхронной функции

Comment: Ошибочка console.log(temp1);

Comment: Сути не меняет.

Comment: Ссылку не скинеш на вопрос

Comment: И возможно ли вообще вытащить body?

Comment: Вот ищу какой лучше

Comment: [Вернуть значение функции](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439028/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), [Вернуть ответ из асинхронной функции](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430712/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)